# How to avoid "flexjson.JSONSerializer" convert Datetime Object to Timestamp? I want string like yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, json, flexjson

I'm using flexjson.JSONSerializer to serialize Java Object, but when serializes Date property, it is converted into Timestamp:

`new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class").serialize(obj);`

How can flexjson convert from Date to String of readable time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTransformer for the same.

```
 new JSONDeserializer().use("person.birthdate", new DateTransformer("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss") ).deserialize( people );
```

Answer (score 1):

For the serializer you should use `JSONSerializer#transform`

```
new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class")
    .transform(new DateTransformer("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"), "creationDate")
    .serialize(obj);
```